# How 'Add Design Change' with magento shell script?

Tags: theme, mysql, design-packages, mage-shell

I want add new theme with magento shell script. I think it's possible with direct access to MySQL 'design_change' table. But I don't know how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create theme in *file-level*

Then using below query for applying the theme into your store

> INSERT INTO 'design_change' ('design_change_id', 'store_id', 'design',
>   'date_from', 'date_to') VALUES ('', 'STORE_ID',
>   'packageName/ThemeName', 'Starting_date', 'END_Date');

[image]
Here

- **design_change_id** should be blank as it primary key.
- **store_id** is the store id of your store where you want
  to apply the the theme.
- **packageName** is the package of theme which is located  at
  `app/design/{area}/{packageName}`. **ThemeName** is the name of theme which will be point to the location `app/design/{area}/{packageName}/{ThemeName}`. Magento *skin* folder location  should be `skin/{area}/{packageName}/{ThemeName}`.
- **date_from** is the  starting date of applying theme
- **date_to** end date of applying theme

### Shell Script:

**If you want do  this using  shell php script then try below code:**

```
<?PHP
require_once "YOUR_MAGENTO_DIR/app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');

$design = Mage::getModel('core/design');
 $design->setData('store_id','STORE_ID');
 $design->setData('design','packageName/ThemeName');
 $design->setData('date_from','YYYY-MM_DD');
 $design->setData('date_to','YYYY-MM_DD');

try {
    $design->save();
     echo  'The design change has been saved.';
} catch (Exception $e){
    $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by a Shell script you mean, a means to do such via Shell with a boot strapped Magento and not just a raw bash script or such.

Familiarize yourself with:

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/shell/abstract.php

It is the same scripts that can be executed via `php -f shell/file.php -- somearguments`

Using Amit's SQL should work or you can utilize the framework with the shell abstract mentioned.